# Error installing Glassfish tools for Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I get this error, how do I fix it?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Software being installed: GlassFish Tools 5.3.0.201307081547 (oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.glassfish.feature.group 5.3.0.201307081547)

Missing requirement: GlassFish Tools UI 5.3.0.201307081547 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui 5.3.0.201307081547) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.8.0,3.9.0)' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:

From: GlassFish Tools 5.3.0.201307081547 (oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.glassfish.feature.group 5.3.0.201307081547)

To: oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui [5.3.0.201307081547]
```

Comment: That looks like you are trying to install code intended for Eclipse Juno on Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

Find the GlassFish version which is compatible with kepler and install it. Looks like you are installing juno only compatible GlassFish.